# How to change User-Agent on Google App Engine UrlFetch service?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Is it possible to change User-Agent of Google App Engine [UrlFetch service](http://code.google.com/intl/it/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok found it, it's possible since [SDK 1.2.1](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2009/04/sdk-version-121-released.html) was released ([Issue 342](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=342)).
You just have to specify the User-Agent header:

```
urlfetch.fetch(url, headers = {'User-Agent': "MyApplication_User-Agent"})
```