# Twitch TV API Call Generates Error 400 in GAE

Tags: python, api, google-app-engine

I've run into this issue in the past, and have been able to work around it until now. When making a call to the Twitch API in app engine, I get an Error 400. I've been to the google groups twitch page, as well as twitch tv's own forum.

I was able to talk to a ton of people at Twitch TV as well as App Engine, and to no luck have I been able to solve this problem. In hopes of clarifying my question, I have been able to make a simple app to replicate directly what is occurring when I try to make a URL call to Twitch TV's API.

Summary:

**This is the simple code that fails when my application is deployed, but works flawlessly in the localhost environment:**

```
import webapp2
import urllib2

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
    url = ('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/nl_kripp')
        contents = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    self.response.out.write(contents.read())


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler)],
                              debug=True)
```

**Here is what this exact application generates when being run on localhost (as it is suppose too):**

{"stream":{"name":"live_user_nl_kripp","game":"Guild Wars 2","viewers":3229,"_links":{"self":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/nl_kripp"},"_id":3681678672,"broadcaster":"fme","channel":{"game":"Guild Wars 2","name":"nl_kripp","created_at":"2012-04-15T02:25:31Z","teams":[{"name":"nolife","created_at":"2012-06-20T23:48:51Z","background":null,"updated_at":"2012-06-20T23:49:08Z","banner":null,"_links":{"self":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/teams/nolife"},"_id":330,"logo":null,"info":"\n","display_name":"noLife"}],"banner":null,"updated_at":"2012-08-26T21:12:55Z","background":"http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/nl_kripp-channel_background_image-527e8b792a46df22.png","url":"http://www.twitch.tv/nl_kripp","logo":"http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/nl_kripp-profile_image-267fd5e2fb95a15d-300x300.png","_id":29795919,"_links":{"stream_key":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/nl_kripp/stream_key","self":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/nl_kripp","chat":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/chat/nl_kripp","commercial":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/nl_kripp/commercial","features":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/nl_kripp/features"},"mature":null,"video_banner":"http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/nl_kripp-channel_offline_image-f3ad1124bc19cffd-640x360.png","display_name":"nl_Kripp","status":"nolife Kripparrian -- GW2 Ranger Lvling. Server = Maguuma"},"preview":"http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews/live_user_nl_kripp-630x473.jpg","partner":true},"_links":{"self":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/nl_kripp"}}

**And now the same exact application in the App Engine environment:**

http://urltestingsite.appspot.com/

I have spent quite a while trying to solve this problem as it is a major chain link in my website. Does anyone, have any remote idea as to why this occurs?

EDIT - this is the code from my actual application:

```
def check_if_live(self, b):
    url = ('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/%s' %b)
    url2 = urlfetch.fetch(url, headers = {'User-Agent': "suitegamer_User-Agent"}) 
    contents = urllib2.urlopen(url2)
    if (contents.read()).find('{"stream":null,') == 0:
        return 'Offline'
    else:
        return 'Live'
```

This code is returning this AttributeError:

```
AttributeError: '_URLFetchResult' object has no attribute 'get_type'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This errors are returned some times when you hit the rate limit or when your app is denied access.

According to [this thread](http://support.twitch.tv/discussion/39/api-rate-limit), it may be what could actually be happening. Since GAE is a shared environment, you will most certainly hit these limits very often, because there could be many users querying the twitch.tv and/or justin.tv (I don't know if the limits are shared between the two).

Also according to [this other thread](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/justintv-api-developers/mWTlv3BYDow/discussion), the api just don't like the GAE production User-Agent (I tried it myself and the problem is still there).

The solution to the second problem is to set the User-Agent (see [How to change User-Agent on Google App Engine UrlFetch service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743521/how-to-change-user-agent-on-google-app-engine-urlfetch-service)), but you will still probably be hitting the rate limits.

Comment: AFAIK, `User-agent` can not be fully edited. You can set your custom UA, but GAE will always append `AppEngine-Google` to the end of it: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=342

Comment: +1 I didn't know that. Fortunately in this case apparently the only offending UA, are those with some text after a colon.

Comment: Thanks guys! I'll give this a shot in a few minutes.

Comment: Alright I gave this a shot with the code I edited the OP with. I am receiving an error... Probably totally my fault.

Comment: You are mixing urlfetch and urllib in a weird way. You get the content of an urlfetch response as response.content (see https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/responseobjects for the whole reference). However, as I pointed out in my answer there are two errors in this case, and the other one is related to the fact that you will most certainly hit the quota limits from GAE, unless there's a way in the API to authenticate your requests.

Comment: Alright, I've got it working again on localhost. However, its failing on app engine. The call is not returning any data at all. When I print the contents on localhost, I can see the data, but when I print it on the GAE environment, I see nothing. I set the user-agent to {'User-Agent': "suitegamer"}. I understand there are also limits to the calls, but I mean, my site is in development. I should be no where near those limits as the only user is myself. This is definitely a step up from what was happening before though. I couldn't even see the webpage before.

Comment: Sorry, if found that urlfetch will actually append the following "AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine; appid: APPID)". So that User-Agent will break Twitch.tv api. I suggest you to contact the TwitchTv api developers to see if they can solve it on their side. However, have in mind that GAE is a shared environment and as such is very probable to hit any rate limit based on IP address.

Comment: Yes I saw that as well, but was unsure if the dash would cause a failure. Thank you very much sir! I've learned a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I feel stupid for answering my own question, however if anyone else runs into this problem, hopefully I spread light onto the issue.

Twitch TV is currently blacklisting any calls from App Engine. I'm sure this is a mistake on their end, but anyways, I tried the same app using ow3d.tv's API and it worked flawlessly. It will probably be fixed in due time, but if it isn't, don't waste your time trying to overcome this issue! Cheers!